# Jquery ui autocomplete - how to tell if the field has been cleared

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way to do that? Basically, I would like to detect when the user clears the field, as there are other fields that depend on that.
I used a change event, but it didn't fire when I cleared the input box.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could check the change and keyup events and then check the length of the value.

Comment: change doesn't fire as I specified.

Comment: Sure it does, it just fires once the field is blurred. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Comment: Think of how annoying change would be if it wasn't blur - if min value if "20" you'd get error after pressing "3" then ok with "30" , then an error with back space to change to "31" - Change is really meant to act like blur but not fire if there was no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a couple different handlers to make sure you catch the user clearing the field

```
$(document).on('keyup, keydown, blur, change' , '.myTxtBox', function(){
var text =  $(this).val();
if text = "" {}    
});
```

some keys are easier to detect on keyup and some on key down , if you want to make sure the user isn't highlighting then deleting , or pressing , delete, backspace , ect. you need a couple of different handlers

Comment: I need exactly this to implement here.                                                                        j$(document).ready(function(){

    j$(".apexaccountautocomplete").autocomplete({
       
        source : apexCIList,
       select: function(event, ui){ this.value = ui.item.value; jsApplyFilter("'" + ui.item.value + "'"); }
     
   });     });  But when I do this autocomplete function even stops working. Please help me identify the issue. I am just an amateur in Javascript , JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *focusout* to check if *text_input* has been cleared (and then clear the *id_input*)

```
// check if autocomplete has been cleared
$("#text_input").focusout(function() {
    if ($("#text_input").val() == '') {
        $('#id_input').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about binding a function to the the jQuery keyup event and, in that function, checking the length of the .val() of the field?

This will work fine in almost all browsers. IE Mobile  9 requires that you set a time delay before reading the field value as the field content is not updated until after the yeyup event.

Note to moderators: stupid web site made me wait 3 minutes to enter this answer - waiting does not make it any more or less right you know.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar approach that Mike suggested but checking the length of `a#ui-active-menuitem` instead of `val()` on the keyup event of the `input[type="text"]` because it's also possible that there's no result selected and the input doesn't be empty. (eg: if the user blur the list results by pressing the up arrow key)

```
input.on('keyup', function(){
    if(! $('a#ui-active-menuitem').length ) ...
});
```